# Does there exist an uncountable separable metric space "directed" in one way by some linear order?

Tags: general-topology

I'm solving a topology exercise and after reductions I need to check the statement below.

Does there exist a separable metrizable dense-in-itself uncountable space $X$ together with a linear order $<$ on $X$ such that for any $x\in X$ the set $[x, \infty)$ is open? Additionally one can assume that there is some minimal element $0\in X$ and that there is a strictly increasing sequence $x_n\in X$ such that if $x\in X$ then $x < x_n$ for some $n$.

Original exercise is to prove that for any separable metrizable space $X$ and its uncountable subset $A$ and any linear order $<$ on $A$ there is $x\in A$ with $$x\in\overline{(-\infty, x)}\cap\overline{(x, \infty)}$$

How I got this is by contradiction I considered $X = A$, then noticed that for uncountably many $x$ we have for example $x\notin \overline{(-\infty, x)}$, so that we can assume for all $x$, and so it follows that $[x, \infty)$ is open for all $x$, and then we can further take a dense-in-itself subspace by Cantor-Brendixon theorem.

Comment: Oh. Do you have a countable example in mind? In the exercise the space is uncountable.

Comment: Yes, I had a countable example in mind.

Comment: @bof maybe you could share it anyway?

Comment: If $C$ is the Cantor set then the components of $[0,1]\setminus C$ are open intervals. Let $X$ be the set consisting of the right-hand endpoints of those intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every separable metric space $X$ with a linear order such that $[x,\infty)$ is open for each $x \in X$ is countable. So no uncountable example exists as you have asked.

For the proof, let $\mathcal B$ be a countable basis of $X$ (every separable metric space has a countable basis).

Since $\mathcal B$ is a basis, there exists a function $X \mapsto \mathcal B$ which associates to each $x \in X$ an element $B_x \in \mathcal B$ such that $x \in B_x \subset [x,\infty)$. Noting that $x$ is the smallest element of $[x,\infty)$, it follows that $x$ is the smallest element of $B_x$. Therefore if $x \ne y$ then $B_x \ne B_y$. This proves that the function $X \mapsto \mathcal B$ is injective.

Since $\mathcal B$ is countable, it follows that $X$ is countable.

Comment: Thank you, I was overthinking it way too much.